# Angular Unit Test using NgbDatepicker is failing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, datepicker, ng-bootstrap

This seems pretty simple, and I'm sure I'm not importing something somewhere, but I've tried all the modules, including the test, and no luck. The test fails with this error:

> There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngbDatepicker"
>   (placeholder="a year ago" [(ngModel)]="fromDate" ngbDatepicker [ERROR->]#fromDateToggle="ngbDatepicker" title="Select a date">

I have a component template that uses the `ng-bootstrap` datepicker in a popup (as per their [docs](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples))

My template code looks like:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input id="to-date" name="dp" class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp" [(ngModel)]="toDate"
    ngbDatepicker #toDateToggle="ngbDatepicker" title="Select a date">
  <button class="input-group-addon" (click)="toDateToggle.toggle()" type="button">
    <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
  </button>
</div>
```

I have `NgbModule.forRoot()` in `app.module.ts` and have imported `NgbModule` in my spec file, which seems to be all that the [guide](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started) requires.

**My spec file:**

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { DebugElement, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgbModule, NgbActiveModal, NgbDateStruct } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ExtractModalComponent } from './extract-modal.component';

fdescribe('ExtractModalComponent', () => {
  let component: ExtractModalComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ExtractModalComponent>;
  let debugEl: DebugElement;

  beforeEach(
    async(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ExtractModalComponent],
        providers: [NgbActiveModal],
        schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
      }).compileComponents();
    })
  );

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ExtractModalComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    debugEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.modal-body'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  fit('should create component', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> "I have NgbModule.forRoot() in app.module.ts"

.... this is irrelevant to your tests. You need to do this in you spec file

e.g. `imports:[NgbModule.forRoot()]`

Worth noting that you don't have to import the full `NgbModule` i.e.: you could just import the `NgbDatepickerModule` ... but I'd get it working first before tinkering with this

Comment: Thanks. I still don't have a great handle on what all needs to be put into the spec file itself, and what (if anything) is taken from any other modules.

Comment: Thank you very much! `imports:[NgbModule.forRoot()]` in the .spec.ts file fixed it. Although I tried `import { NgbDatepickerModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/datepicker/datepicker.module';` instead, the error came back.

Comment: to import an individual item do the followingL  import { NgbDatepickerModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';  and then imports: [    NgbDatepickerModule .forRoot()  ]

Comment: I have got  'Property 'forRoot' does not exist on type 'typeof NgbModule' error

Comment: because they removed it in 2019

Comment: So what's the solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use imports: [ NgbModule ] and it will fix the problem. forRoot() is not required now and has been removed.

Note: Never forget to write import on the top: *import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';*